# Streaming video across WEB API 2

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, audio, audio-streaming

I need to streaming audio-file from server, which wrote on С# and use WEB API2, to IOS- and Android- client.
Maybe somebody know a good library for this or specialize protocol and good format with codec?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

We provided the audio-video streaming for one of the our project recently. It can be performed by splitting the media file and pushing to client side as partial. `PushStreamContent` is the key feature to enable it.

So, there is a very good tutorial and an example [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/andresv/asynchronous-streaming-in-asp-net-webapi).